# Copying dynamically allocated char* string into new char* string

Tags: c, string, memory, dynamic

I will appreciate him who can help me. Please note that I am programming in CLR (Common Language Run Time) with visual studio 2010. I have assigned character to a string with dynamic memory allocation. Now I want to copy it in another static string. But when I print the static one after copying it is copying the main string with some garbage character. I need to remove the garbage characters. Help me please.

```
int i;
char *encode_data,*copy_data;
    encode_data=(char*)malloc(5*sizeof(char));
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
      {
        *(encode_data+i)='a';

      }
copy_data=encode_data;
printf("\nEncode Data= ");
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
      { 
       printf("%c",*(encode_data+i));
      }
printf("\nCopy Data= %s",copy_data);
free(encode_data);
```

But the output is printing some '2' as power. I need to copy_data as a string only which I entered in encode_data. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to null terminate your string by appending `\0` at the end of string.

```
encode_data = malloc(6*sizeof(char));
for( i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    encode_data[i] = 'a'; 
encode_data[i] = '\0';
```

Comment: Thanks printing ok but another run time error occurred heap corruption detected after normal block #60. Ok it is ok now you declared it for 6 characters. Thanks. @haccks

Answer (score 0):

The copied string is not zero terminated. You can print a string without a zero terminator like this:

```
int copy_data_len = 5;
printf("\nCopy Data= %.*s", copy_data_len, copy_data);
```

Alternatively allocate one more character for the zero terminator and set it to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Character array the first element of which is pointed to by encode_data and then by copy_data is not zero-terminated. 
Format specifier `%s` of function `printf` expects that the printed array is zero-terminated. So the function outputs characters until it will encountered a byte with zero.

To get the correct result you should output the array the following way

```
printf("\nCopy Data= %5.5s",copy_data);
```